# Why baskervald(x) is as semibold as default?

Tags: fonts, symbols

The `baskervald(x)` package is a clone of the `Baskerville` font. If I make a comparison between this image (extract of a Physics book)

[image]

and my MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{baskervald}
\usepackage[baskervaldx]{newtxmath}
\begin{document} 
\[\Delta t=t_f-t_i\]
\end{document}
```

I obtain this:

[image]

In mathematical mode, is there a possibility to make the characters lighter as the first picture?

Comment: I don't see anything unexpected in the f(x)=\frac example produced by your example? The math font is a virtual font  so non alphabetic symbols are pulled from elsewhere (rtxr font) but the italic letters match the non math text as far as I can tell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fonts used in math do not seem any bolder than the text fonts, I changed the example to more easily compare. the fonts used for `\mathrm` and `\mathit` are identical to the text upright and italic, the font used for the default math italic as expected has wider sidebearings but is no bolder.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{librebaskerville}
\usepackage{baskervald}
\usepackage[baskervaldx]{newtxmath}
\showoutput
\begin{document} 
This is an example.

$\mathrm{This\ is\ an\ example.}$

\textit{This is an example.}

$This\ is\ an\ example.$

$\mathit{This\ is\ an\ example.}$

\end{document}
```

`pdffonts` reports the fonts in the PDF as

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
VCRPNQ+BaskervaldADFStd-Regular      Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       4  0
GWOGHS+rtxmi                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       5  0
LNASWP+BaskervaldADFStd-Italic       Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       6  0
UCLGTI+Baskervaldx-Ita               Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       7  0
```

Comment: Voted positively. But I'm not very convinced. Compared to the first image and my output, the mathematical characters - see for example the subscripts - are lighter.

Comment: @Sebastiano the font is just mechanically scaled so the subscripts are smaller and thinner that is just the way it is in almost all font sets other than cm that has a large collection of designed size fonts.

Comment: Please look at the comparison between `\[\Delta t=t_f-t_i\]`
of the first image and my last MWE. In my opinion but I do not insist the character of the first image has the characters less thick.

Comment: @Sebastiano Your question was rather hard to read, i thought that you were saying that the weight of math and text within the same example did not match, I mainly addressed that. It looks like all these have a heavier font than the first image you show but with website resolution pngs and no source for your first image that isn't very informative and anyway it is not surprising if different digital versions of classic fonts have visible differences

Comment: I'm not good in English. I'm sorry. You are allowed to improve and make my application more readable.

Comment: @Sebastiano It wasn't clear what you were comparing in these two phrases, they appear to be contradictory (one saying math was too bold, one saying it was too light) but I think you were comparing different things?  "it can be observed that in mathematical mode the mathematical characters are lighter"  v  " in mathematical mode, is there a possibility to make the characters lighter"

Comment: Exact and perfect answer. I'm using the translator. Courtesy if you could edit my question is better to make it understandable to all. I then get it into my head to change it many times because I wouldn't know exactly how to write it at its best.

Comment: @Sebastiano  I can not translate it if I do not know what it means.